# Generic method for max Id field for multiple classes

Tags: c#, linq

I have many classes from which I need to calculate **max+1** number from **numeric** field at Save(). And it does have same name across all classes.

Is there any way to implement (generic) method so I can always call it without duplicating my code whenever I need to calculate max Id? It's always **same numeric** field and there are different classes involved.

Database is MS SQL.

Or is there any c# method that can do that? Linq maybe?

edited:
It's not Id field from DB.

edit 2:
user can  enter manually some number in this field. If not, my program should calculate max+1 number for it.

Comment: Take a step back and define your use case, your model structure, etc.  A "generic method to add 1 to an integer" is kind of meaningless.  You can't really make `+1` or `++` *simpler*.  Provide more context about the problem.

Comment: @mjwills I use custom framework based on EF. It's MS SQL database.

Comment: @mjwills Identity column is for PK, this field is like regular number field. I will edit my main question, it's not **Id IDENTITY** field that I need to get max number.

Comment: If you do persist down this line, I **strongly** suggest that you put a UNIQUE INDEX on the column that you are MAXing to deal with the inevitable race condition.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your classes all have the `Id` property, you can create an interface `public interface IEntity { int Id {get;set;} }` then just call `listOfStuff.Cast<IEntity>().Max(entity => entity.Id);`

You need to be aware that this fails if `listOfStuff` is empty. You will have to guard against this with something like `DefaultIfEmpty`.

Comment: I will try with this one for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can define such method at the base class, where `int Id` property is defined.
Mark it as protected in order to allow subclasses to access it.
However, it does not need to be generic unless you use different types of `Id`. If such, than you'd need to implement `abstract protected TId GetNext(TId)` function, which is to be called every time you need next value.

However, it is wrong way to go. You'd better rely on database to achieve that. The only exception - is that you need `+1` not to produce new id for some new instance, but you business domain requires it (which I considered to be almost impossible). So - don't do it, rely on a DB you use.